# Brownian motion - Hölder continuity

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B$ stand for a Brownian motion on a finite interval $[0,1]$. If I am not wrong, I think that there exists a positive constant $c$, such that almost surely, for $h$ small enough , for all $0< t < 1- h$

\begin{align}
|B(t+h)-B(t)| < c\sqrt{h\log(1/h)}
\end{align}
or something like this. As a result

\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{B(t+h)-B(t)}{h}\bigg| < K(h) 
\end{align}

Am I correct ?

Comment: The inequality cannot hold with probability 1 since the random variable B(T')-B(t) is unbounded. Please clarify.

Comment: Oops, yes of course, what a nonsense I wrote!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the result is known as Lévy's modulus of continuity:

> Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a (one-dimensional) Brownian motion. Then $$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{h \to 0} \frac{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1-h} |B(t+h)-B(t)|}{\sqrt{2h |\log h|}} = 1 \right)=1.$$

See e.g. *René Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: Brownian motion - An introduction to stochastic processes* for a proof (Section 10.3).